# How can I get data from database into HTML table?

Tags: html, mysql

How can I bring up team results from my db into a html table?

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s1` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`team` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `s1` (`ID`, `team`) VALUES
(1, 'test1'),
(2, 'test2');
```

**HTML table:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><p> team name (test1) </p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p> team name (test2) </p></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Overly broad.  What backend language are you using?  PHP, Ruby?  Python?  What have you tried?  You should post your attempted code here.

Comment: i usese php language! thk

Comment: But you don't use PHP language do you, as you're asking us to write it for you. This is lesson 1 in PHP school. You need to show some effort.

Comment: Indeed, this is very very basic. Ready this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need PHP for this

first you have to connect PHP with your db

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("YourHost","user","password","dbName") or die('connection to DB failed');
```

then you need a query to get the team names

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT team FROM s1");
```

now you need a array to save the DB values

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

the connection to the DB can now be closed

```
mysqli_close($connection);
```

after all you can print the values in the table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><p> team name <?php if(isset($row[0])){
echo $row[0]; 
}else{
echo 'noName';
} ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p> team name <?php if(isset($row[1])){
echo $row[1]; 
}else{
echo 'noName';
} ?></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this should work

Comment: i test it, but I can not let out the second row of the db. (test2)

Comment: thats means the variable row [1] is not set. Could you post your hole mysql-code?